# Javascript Promise Anti-pattern

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I have a `Promise`, but it is not working as I want because the async call is not finished when I try use the data.

I have been looking [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/) at Promise ant-patterns, and I am sure this is my fix. However, because I am weak at Javascript, I am struggling to implement their suggestion.  If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

**My code:**

```
  private findLocalChatsWithLastMessageForChat(): Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> {
    let promise: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> = new Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>>(resolve => {
      let localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);
      for (let i: number = 0; i < this.chatsStorageService.chats.length; i++) {
        let chat: Chat = this.chatsStorageService.chats[i];
        let findLastMessageForChatPromise: Promise<Message> = this.chatsStorageService.findLastMessageForChat(chat);
        findLastMessageForChatPromise.then((data) => {
          let message: Message = data;
          chat.lastMessage = message;
          chat.lastMessageCreatedAt = message.createdAt;
          localChatCollection.insert(chat);
        });
      }
      resolve(localChatCollection);
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

As you can see, the promise returns to the calling function, before the `this.chatsStorageService.findLastMessageForChat` promises are finished.

Reading [here](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/), offers this solution:

```
function workMyCollection(arr) {
    return q.all(arr.map(function(item) {
        return doSomethingAsync(item);
    }));    
}
```

However, I don't know how to amend my Typescript code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is your `resolve(localChatCollection)` which is resolving your `Promise` without waiting for previous promises.

You have to store all your Promise in an array and wait them all before resolving.

Note that I don't know TypeScript I let you translate if I'm wrong about the syntax.

```
 private findLocalChatsWithLastMessageForChat(): Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> {
    let promise: Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>> = new Promise<Mongo.Collection<Chat>>(resolve => {
      let localChatCollection: Mongo.Collection<Chat> = new Mongo.Collection<Chat>(null);

      // -----------------
      // ARRAY OF PROMISES 
      let promises: Array<Promise> = [];
      // -----------------

      for (let i: number = 0; i < this.chatsStorageService.chats.length; i++) {
        let chat: Chat = this.chatsStorageService.chats[i];
        let findLastMessageForChatPromise: Promise<Message> = this.chatsStorageService.findLastMessageForChat(chat);

        // -----------------
        // PUSH ALL YOUR PROMISES IN promises ARRAY
        promises.push(findLastMessageForChatPromise);
        // -----------------

        // Binding 'chat' in order to don't loose it.
        findLastMessageForChatPromise.then(function (_chat, data) {
          let message: Message = data;
          _chat.lastMessage = message;
          _chat.lastMessageCreatedAt = message.createdAt;
          localChatCollection.insert(_chat);
        }.bind(null, chat));
      }

      // -----------------
      // WAIT FOR ALL PROMISES BEFORE RESOLVING
      Promise.all(promises).then(function() {resolve(localChatCollection);});
      // -----------------

    });
    return promise;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try

Comment: hum there will be some problem with your `chat` variable. I will update my answer

Comment: You still need to avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!